# Compare two columns in sheet1 with two columns in sheet two and display a value from sheet 2

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a horse show points spreadsheet where horses names and riders need to be matched up with the same pairs from other sheets.  So, column 1 being the horse name, and column 2 being the rider name, I would like to display the point total from another sheet with the same horse/rider pair.

So, sheet1`row1 column 3 would need to find the same horse/rider pair (column a and b) from sheet 2 and display the point total (which is totaled in sheet2 column q of some row wherever that horse/rider pair is listed).

I'm not sure where to start with creating a formula like this.  I did try with vlookup, but that doesn't seem to allow me to make an array of two columns and compare that with another array which I think is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find the simplest solution (other than running a macro someone else has written for you of course) is to insert a column at the extreme left of both sheets and put something like `=B2&" | "&C2` in Row2 of those columns (assumes your other columns have labels) then copy down and use a formula such as:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet 2'!A:R,18,FALSE),"")
```

(also in Row2 and copied down) to look up the points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA, you can insert a new module and copy this code in. Then you can use the function in a cell with **=GetPointTotal(`HorseCell`, `RiderCell`)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetPointTotal(horseRange As Range, riderRange As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, searchRange As Range
    Dim displaySheet As Worksheet, pointSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iEndRow As Integer
    Dim horseCol As String, riderCol As String, pointCol As String, points As String
    Dim b As Boolean


    'Configuration
    Set displaySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set pointSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    horseCol = "A"
    riderCol = "B"
    pointCol = "Q"
    'EndConfiguration

    iEndRow = pointSheet.Range(horseCol & 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set searchRange = pointSheet.Range(horseCol & 1 & ":" & horseCol & iEndRow)

    b = False
    For Each cell In searchRange
        If b = True Then Exit For
        If cell.Value2 = horseRange.Value2 Then
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = riderRange.Value2 Then
                points = pointSheet.Range(pointCol & cell.Row).Value2
                b = True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    GetPointTotal = points

End Function
```

Comment: @pnuts It can be whatever column he wants, that's why it's under the `Configuration` section. You set the column letters and sheet names to be whatever you want. But I changed it to `Q` to reflect the OP's question